# export a string from poweshell 1 to powershell 2

Tags: powershell, shell

I have a shell script file.

```
./1.ps1
./2.ps1
```

I generate a string such as `env-0` in `1.ps1` and need to export it to `2.ps1`.
**UPDATE:**

1.ps1 generate many string and I couldn't pass my env-0 as argument to `2.ps1`.

Do you have another solution?

Comment: There are multiple ways of going about this. Is `env-0` the only value you want to output from `1.ps1` and feed to `2.ps1`?

Comment: each time I run 1.ps1 it generates a new string. Yes I feed to 2.ps2

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell's stream-like I/O model is a little unusual, but *any value not captured* is basically output - so to output the string `env-0` from `1.ps1`, this is literally all you need:

```
"env-0"
```

Now that `1.ps1` outputs a string value, we need some way to feed it to `2.ps1`.

You can either rely on *unbound positional arguments*, which will automatically be available in the target script/function via the `$args` variable:

```
# 2.ps1
$envString = $args[0]

# work with your `$envString` value here
```

To invoke:

```
$envString = ./1.ps1
./2.ps1 $envString
# or
./2.ps1 $(./1.ps1)
```

---

You can also accept *pipeline* input by consuming the `$input` automatic input enumerator variable:

```
# 2.ps1
$input |ForEach-Object {
    $envString = $_
    # work with your `$envString` value here
}
```

To invoke:

```
./1.ps1 |./2.ps1
```

This might be useful if you intend to provide *multiple* inputs to `2.ps1` in succession:

```
# This will execute `./1.ps1` 100 times, but `./2.ps1` will only be executed once, and the output continuously fed to it as pipeline input
1..100 |ForEach-Object { ./1.ps1 } | ./2.ps1
```

---

Finally, if you want to write scripts for more advanced scenarios (multiple input parameters, input validation, argument completion etc.), you'll want to explicitly declare named parameter(s) with a `param()` block:

```
# ./2.ps1
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$Environment
)

# work with $Environment here
```

To invoke:

```
./2.ps1 -Environment $(./1.ps1)
```

It's worth noting that you can use the `[Parameter()]` attribute to modify the binding behavior so you still get pipeline support:

```
# ./2.ps1
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Environment
)

# work with $Environment here
```

Now that we've added both the `Position` and a `ValueFromPipeline` flags, we can pass the string via the pipeline, by name, or positionally all at once:

```
# These all work now
./2.ps1 -Environment $(./1.ps1)
./2.ps1 $(./1.ps1)
./1.ps1 |./2.ps1
```

The only caveat is that you can't pipe *multiple* input values anymore - for that, you'll need to move the script body into a special `process` block:

```
# ./2.ps1
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Environment
)

process {
  # work with $Environment here
}
```

The `process` block will execute exactly once for each pipeline input, so now piping multiple values works again ()along with the previous 3 examples:

```
1..100 |ForEach-Object { ./1.ps1 } | ./2.ps1
```

So that's my solution:

```
# 1.ps1
"env-0"
```

```
# 2.ps1
# ./2.ps1
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$Environment
)

process {
  # work with $Environment here
}
```

For more information about advanced parameters and their binding semantics and how to utilise them, see the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#attributes-of-parameters)

Comment: By the way, my `1.ps1` generate many strings, because it comminucating with vCeneter and generate many output. I can't give 1.ps1 output to 2.ps1.

Comment: @PersianGulf It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided those details in your question :) Are these outputs that you _need_ for something?

Comment: @PersianGulf You're not really answering my questions... please try: Is this output _needed_ for consumption else where? Are you in a position to modify `1.ps1`? Does the output string you're specifically interested in have any special characteristics (like, is it the only output that starts with "env" for example)?

Comment: Now, I don't need them, But 1.ps1 generates them. I don't have time to modify.Yes, according to such as env-0 or other string I have to decide in 2.ps1.

Comment: Then filter the output from `1.ps1`: `./2.ps1 $(./1.ps1 |Where-Object {$_ -like 'env-*'} |Select -First 1)`